# Excel VBA Macro to add a row when value changes and populate that row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to build a macro in excel that will take a bunch of data like this:

```
D 1 2 3 4 5
D 1 2 3 9 5
D 1 2 3 4 5
```

And process it to insert a row when a value in column 4 differs.  I also want to populate this row at the same time with either static values or a formula.

So ideally, taking the above table I would get:

```
D 1 2 3 4 5
H A B C D E   <- This row got added as there was a change in column D
D 1 2 3 9 5
H A B C D E   <- This row got added as there was a change in column D
D 1 2 3 4 5
```

I would want this to iterate through a quite long list.

Can anyone give me any pointers?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You want to **iterate through a quite long list** .. why ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. I didn't test it but if you run it and use F8 to iterate through it should be easy to debug if it doesn't work exactly as intended.

```
Dim i as integer

for i = 2 to cells(1,1).end(xldown).row 'itereate thru all rows
  if cells(i,4).value <> cells(i-1,4).value then 'compare the cells in col 4 with previous row
    rows(i).entirerow.insert 'insert a row if the values don't match
    cells(i,1) = "A"
    cells(i,2) = "B"
    cells(i,3) = "C"
    cells(i,4) = "D"
    cells(i,5) = "E"

    i = i + 1 'since we inserted a row we have to make i bigger to go down
  end if
next i
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but this hits a 1004 error at this line:

Rows(i).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown 'insert a row if the values don't match

Comment: try getting rid of the sfhit:=xldown business